# How to post on AliExpress

Tags: aliexpress

Under “My Profile” on AliExpress.com, I have a section called “My Post”.

As I click on it I get the following message:

> No posts yet! Add your first post soon on our APP.

So I go over to the AliExpress app, but can't find any section where I can post something.

Does anyone know how to post, and know what it is good for?